# perl split string using regex but join the delimiter to the output

Tags: string, perl, split

I have a string like:

```
za b c
   x y
   x z
ya b c
   x y
   x z
```

Now if I split as:

```
my @lines = split /\n([a-z])/, $input;
my @sorted_lines = sort @lines;
```

The input line is split into three parts as:

```
za b c
   x y
   x z

y

a b c
  x y
  x z
```

Is there a way to split based on newline+somecharacter, but retain that character to the next token ? I mean I want the output to have only two tokens as: 1) za ... and 2) ya ....

Comment: Did you mean `[a-z]`?

Comment: ah yes. Thanks. I missed the regex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the regex to [look ahead](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) without capturing with `(?=...)`:

```
my @lines = split /\n(?=[a-z])/, $input;
```